# Why is there a 6880*2880 resolution on my Xiaomi 34" curved monitor

Tags: graphics-cards, monitors, windows

I just bought my shinny new screen and the last one I bought was 8 years ago.

It's [Xiaomi 34" Curved 144Hz Gamining Monitor](https://www.mi-store.com.au/xiaomi-mi-curved-gaming-monitor-34#additional)

On Windows 10, I was surprised to see there is a resolution: 6880 * 2880!!!

[image]

Oh dear, I checked the specs of this monitor, but on its official website, it's 3400*1440.

I also checked in Ubuntu 20.04, I do not have that high resolution.

Could anyone explain why this is happening?

Btw, my GPU is NVIDIA RTX 2080 Ti.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be that you have Nvidia DSR enabled.
to check: open up Nvidia control panel, go to Manage 3d setting and search for DSR-Factors. in your case 2.00x might be enabled